# Why was my answer referring to UAP deleted?

Tags: discussion, deleted-answers

In [this question](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/54302/how-serious-is-the-problem-of-interstellar-dust-for-interstellar-space-travel/54313?noredirect=1#comment207811_54313), I posted the following answer, which was unilaterally deleted by a moderator:

> ### UAPs got here somehow.
>
> So, about a month ago [at the time I wrote this answer, in July 2021] the United States government has issued [a report](https://www.dni.gov/files/ODNI/documents/assessments/Prelimary-Assessment-UAP-20210625.pdf) on Unidentified Aerial Phenomena (UAPs), which is basically the modern US government term for UFOs, stating that they're real, they're not American, they do things beyond our current understanding of physics, and they don't know what they are. The actual wording of the report seems to be couched in deliberate understatement, but that's what the facts as presented by the report boil down to. Indeed, the information in the report was significant enough that Avi Loeb, the professor in charge of Astronomy at Harvard University, has begun [a project](https://projects.iq.harvard.edu/galileo/reading) to place meter-wide automated telescopes across the country in the hopes of capturing high-resolution images of them.
>
> If the UAPs are extraterrestrial (rather than extradimensional, time travelers, a prehuman species living in habitats in unexplored areas on the bottom of the ocean, or something similar), then presumably they got to Earth somehow. This implies that interstellar dust isn't a problem for interstellar space flight, or at least whatever form of interstellar flight that they originally used to arrive here.
>
> There's a lot of open questions about what UAPs are, how they work, and where they come from, but I suppose you could consider their existence evidence that interstellar travel may be possible.

The moderator left the following comment, which was completely incorrect:

> nick - your post doesn't even attempt to answer the question, but just seems like you took an opportunity to post some badly thought out rant. Please read our tour and [How to Answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-answer) pages again.

Not only was this answer not in any way a rant, it *did* answer the question that had been asked about interstellar dust posing a hazard to spaceflight - namely, that there is evidence that it doesn't pose a hazard to interstellar flight (or that the hazard can be mitigated), because the UAPs got here somehow if theyre extraterrestrial spacecraft.

My answer *was* heavily downvoted, presumably because of lingering bias against UAP, even though they are now officially recognised by the US government and studied by mainstream academics, but I don't think that the moderator should have unilaterally deleted my answer like this.

Could my answer please be undeleted?

Comment: Suggestion:Calm down and listen to what people are telling you @nick012000

Comment: I have to agree with you. The answer does not trigger any "mod must delete" criteria that I'm aware of. It should be left visible to the community, and the community can decorate it with comments and with the voting buttons to their heart's content.

Answer (score 6):

The moderation was correct. Even if we ignore that there's no evidence UAPs are extraterrestrial, and therefore they can't reflect on the hazards of interstellar dust, **a hypothetical interstellar UAP might still have to mitigate dust hazards**.  There's no way to tell from what's known about UAPs (which is nearly nothing, down to details about their shape).

Space SE answers have to be supported by facts, and without facts about UAPs, your answer can't be.

On a similar tack:  even if we took for granted both that UAPs are extraterrestrial, and that they do interstellar travel, the question isn't "can interstellar dust be overcome?"  The question in the title is "How serious is the problem of interstellar dust for interstellar space travel?" and the final sentence of the post is "Does presence of a viscous interstellar medium place any practical restrictions on the speed of interstellar travel?"  Your post doesn't come close to answering either.  The other answer actually addresses the question.

Comment: It's asking if it poses a hazard, and the presence of UAPs is evidence that it doesn't. A hazard that's technologically mitigated isn't really a hazard. "How serious?" "Not very. If it poses a risk, interstellar UAPs solved it."

Comment: @nick012000 if you presuppose that something exists that solves a problem, it means that the problem isn't very serious?

Answer (score 4):

Um, because it **doesn't answer the question**. The report has little to nothing to do with the question and has little conclusive details. Your answer is not really based on it and also doesn't really answer the question. That is why I flagged it as not an answer.

Answer (score 4):

Also, your answer is factually incorrect. You have seriously mischaracterized the contents of that report. It does not state in any way that interstellar travel has occurred.

Comment: Did I say that it stated interstellar travel had occurred?

Comment: @nick012000 Yes. "This implies that interstellar dust isn't a problem for interstellar space flight, ..." Your argument was that interstellar dust couldn't be a problem since interstellar travel had occurred. If you are now saying that interstellar travel didn't occur, your post is utterly irrelevant  to the question that was asked, and deserved to be deleted for that reason. Wrong or irrelevant, pick one.

Answer (score 4):

As well as act on flags, clean up messes and generally act as janitors, one of the things elected moderators **are** expected to do is unilaterally take action where needed.

Your post explicitly does not answer the question asked - whether or not I believe your comments about UAP, they are not vaguely relevant to the question. UAP's, if they exist, would likely be very different to our own space craft so trying to infer any challenges we would face from interstellar dust from UAPs is irrelevant.

Instead of trying to answer the question, your post focuses on arguing that UAPs exist, which really doesn't help the OP and looks like you are using your post as an opportunity to spread your beliefs.

And that doesn't meet site requirements. That is why I deleted it.